# Get count of specific nodes between two specific sibling nodes

Tags: html-agility-pack, nodes, xpath-1.0

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to get a filtered DOM of `<h2>` and `<h3>` nodes and using Xpath 1.0 (from my Xpath 1.0 crash course this week) I need to get the number of `<h3>`'s (the number varies) that are between sibling `<h2>`'s as follows:

```
<div>

  <h2>heading 1</h2>

  <h3>sub 1.1</h3>
  <h3>sub 1.2</h3>

  <h2>heading 2</h2>

  <h3>sub 2.1</h3>

  <h2>heading 3</h2>
  ....

</div>
```

When I iterate (using C#) through the filtered nodes I want the exact number of `<h3>`'s that are after a `<h2>` and before the next `<h2>`. When I use the following I get all the `<h3>`'s as the result.

```
int countH3 = n.SelectNodes("./preceding-sibling::h2[2]/following-sibling::h2[3]/preceding-sibling::h3").Count(); //the [position] is set dynamically
```

For the node structure above would like the result of the code line to be:

```
countH3 = 1
```

but it is:

```
countH3 = 3
```

I've found many similar SO questions regarding "sibling nodes between sibling nodes" and have to thank @LarsH for his comment in another question that `/preceding::h3` returns ALL `<h3>'s` which helped explain the issue. I think I may need to use the Kayessian method of node-set intersection but get the "invalid token" error when I include the `. |` union character as follows:

```
countH3 = n.SelectNodes("./h2[2]/following-sibling::h2[3]
   [count(.|./h2[2]/following-sibling::h2[3]/preceding-sibling::h3)=
   count(./h2[2]/following-sibling::h2[3]/preceding-sibling::h3)]").Count();
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Don't you have one dot (.) to many in your first count? Shouldn't it really be `count(.|/h2...)` and not `count(.|./h2...)` ?

Comment: Thanks I changed that but now get a "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source" message.

Comment: It feels like a simple piece of C# code would make your life so much easier. Just iterate through the `div.Elements` and do the count in C# instead in Xpath. It would actually result in readable code as well...

Comment: (btw the Parameter name: source could not be null is coming from the fact that your SelectNodes call returns null, it can't find any nodes that fit your criteria. Have you tried that XPath in any other XML tool to see if it returns anything before stuffing it into the HAP?)

Comment: @jessehouwing Thank you, I've actually worked around this using something similar to your suggestions and with the workaround have been able to move ahead a bit but want to return and get to the bottom of this properly starting with another XPath processor as you've also suggested. The 'workaround' involves getting the total number of `<h3>`'s and subtracting the iteration count as we go.